# Can't copy or delete certain files and explorer.exe uses over 50% CPU

Tags: windows-explorer

Not sure what to do. I can't copy, overwrite or delete certain files in certain locations, like the desktop. They look like they are copying or deleting but the get stuck at 0%. Also, explorer.exe sometimes uses upwards of 50% to 90% CPU. This makes the system pretty unusable.

I ran SFC and it says "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Sounds like it may be a bad hard drive.  Have you checked Event Viewer for disk errors? also try running chkdsk and see if it comes back with bad sectors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what to look for in event viewer, but chkdsk found no problems.

Comment: Windows Windows version do you use?

Comment: Do you get the same problem with a brand new account?